# How to calculate the standard deviation of series?

Tags: probability

Coin flip (heads = 0 and tails = 1). A series of repetitions = 2 = (00 or 11), 3 = (000 or 111)...

The mathematical expectation (for 100 flip) =
1 {0 and 1} = 25;
2 {00 and 11} = 12;
3 = 6;
4 = 3;
5 = 1 or 2;
6 = 0 or 1.

Tell me how to calculate the standard deviation of these series.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are talking about a **binomial distribution**. I do not know what

> The mathematical expectation (for 100 flip) = 1 {0 and 1} = 25; 2 {00 and 11} = 12; 3 = 6; 4 = 3; 5 = 1 or 2; 6 = 0 or 1.

means, please explain better, but in general the variance of a binomial distribution if n(p)(1-p), and the standard deviation is simply the square root of that.

Comment: In 100 somersaults of coin 0 and 1 there will be 25 pieces. 00 and 11 there will be 12 pieces. And so on.